# VBA to filter entire Excel workbook by date by way of SQL backend

Tags: sql, excel, vba, spreadsheet

So I currently have a workbook that has several sheets of pivottables sourced from a SQL database that is updated every hour but has another process that takes a snapshot once per day and date-stamps that snapshot.  Every table in SQL has a column for date.  I'd like to create a copy of that workbook that has a master drop down showing all of the available dates from the database, allow me to select a date and reference ONLY those rows with that date for all tables in the entire workbook.

Too much for excel?

Comment: You can do the filtering in Excel with MS Query. This post is old, but still helpful: http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/12/13/parameters-in-excel-external-data-queries/. This allows you to use Views in SQL Server, so that the processing is done on that end, so it might not be too much for Excel.

Comment: Ah!  This gave me an idea to push me into the right direction with research.  You can use a slicer and connect it to multiple pivottables.  Since I use the same column name for all of my tables, I have a single slicer that controls the filtering of ALL tables.  Brilliant.  Thank you for the hint!